# Is there a link between conditional densities and conditional CDFs?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I have just read a measure theoretical discussion of conditional expectations and conditional densities. I am confused about the following:

We know that for random variables $X$ and $Y$ (real valued, integrable, defined on $(\Omega,\mathcal A, P)$) $$\mathbb E(X \mid Y) = g(Y)=\mathbb E(X\mid Y=\cdot) \circ Y$$ ($P$-a.s.).

We also know that $$\mathbb E(X\mid Y=y)=\int x \frac{f(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}\ \mathsf d \lambda(x)$$ ($P_Y$ a.s.) and we call $$f(x\mid y):=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$$ conditional **density**.

If $f(x\mid y)$ is a density, then it defines a probability measure $$\nu(A)=\int_{A}f(x\mid y)\ \mathsf d\lambda(x)$$ for all $A \in \mathcal B^1$, moreover this measure has a distribution function $$G(x) = \int_{(-\infty,x]}f(x\mid y)\ \mathsf d\lambda(x)=\frac{\int_{(-\infty,x]}f(x,y)\ \mathsf d\lambda(x)}{f_Y(y)}.$$

1. Is there any insightful relationship between $\nu$ and $X,Y, \mathbb E(X\mid Y)$?
2. Conditional CDF is defined as $F(x\mid y)=\frac{F_{X,Y}(x,y)}{F_Y(y)}$. Is there any insightful relationship between $G(x)$ and $F(x\mid y)$? If there is none, is not it strange that $F$ and not $G$ is called conditional CDF?

Comment: "Conditional CDF is defined as $F(x∣y)=F_{X,Y}(x,y)/F_Y(y)$" Huh? Any source for this?

Comment: @Did please take a look (second page) http://www.colorado.edu/economics/morey/7818/jointdensity/NotesonConditionalCDFs/ConditionalCDF_Edward.pdf

Comment: This text defines the conditional PDF $F$ as $F(x\mid y)=P(X\leqslant x\mid Y\leqslant y)$. More usual is the definition $F(x\mid y)=P(X\leqslant x\mid Y=y)$, which in turn is a shortcut for $F(x\mid y)=g_x(y)$ where $g_x(Y)=P(X\leqslant x\mid Y)$ (hence, to answer your question, indeed it is strange to call conditional PDF the function $F$ introduced in this text).